# Solution for extracting a specific part of value from data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have trouble to extract a specific part from the data frame column. I have 2 columns, Id and Value. One cell from column value looks like this:

```
{Blabla1= blabla, Blabla2=blabla BLa blabla, Blabla3 = blabla, Blabla4 = blabla, Blabla5=blabla, Blabla6=blabla}
```

So my question is how to take only Blabla3 value and to store it in the third column called Names? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the Value column?

Comment: It is a type of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it with **regexp_extract**.  `"""(?<=\, Blabla3=)(.*?)(?=\,)"""`